# Mean value theorem $f'(c)$ question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a question relating to the MVT.

Does there exist a differentiable function $f(x)$ defined on $[1,10]$ such that $f(1)=10$, $f(10)=100$ and $f'(x)<10$ for all $x$ in $(1,10)$. If yes provide an example of such a function.If no explain why.

This is what I did I know f is differentiable on $(0,10)$ f is continuous by the mvt for some c in $(1,10)$

$f'(c)=\frac{f(10)-f(1)}{10-1}$ so $f'(c)=10$ but I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: I think you mean that $f$ is differentiable on $(1,10)$, not on $(0,2)$.

Comment: You're done! What is your assumption on $f'$?

Comment: yes sorry i mean(1,10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you are are asked if it can be the case that for $f(x)$ as described, $f'(x) < 10$ for all $x \in [0, 10]$.

So you've shown that there exists $c \in [0, 10]$ such that $f'(c) = 10 \not \lt 10$.

So what does that mean? It means it cannot be the case that $f'(x) \lt 10$ for every $x \in [0, 10]$

i.e. You've proven that it there cannot be such a function.

Comment: thanks that makes sense because in a way it is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, indeed! You've done the work: now just connect the results to conclude such a function cannot exist.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically done. You've just shown that some $x=c$ in the interval $(1,10)$ has the property $f'(x)=10$, so we *can't* have $f'(x)<10$ for all $x$ in the interval.

Answer (score 2):

By the MVT, there exists $x\in(1,10)$ such that $f'(x)=\frac{f(10)-f(1)}{10-1}=\frac{90}9=10$, hence we cannot have $f'(x)<10$ for all $x\in(1,10)$.